# How to calculate the outcome of difference between two fields from hibernate and show it on a jsp?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am making a simple CRUD app, using spring mvc, hibernate and mySQL.

I have a single table in mySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_name` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `quantity_needed` INT DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` INT DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have the basics fixes - listing all of the elements on a JSP, adding a new element, updating and deleting.
I want to also show a separate list with just the products, where the status value < quantity_needed **with the difference being shown**. I created the code to show just the list(without anything else). Below is a part of my *productDAOImpl*:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public List<Product> buyList() {

    // get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    // query the database to find the requested items
    Query<Product> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Product p where p.status<p.quantityNeeded");

    // get the result list
    List<Product> buyList = theQuery.getResultList();

    return buyList;
}
```

and a the *controller*:

```
@GetMapping("/buy")
public String buyList(Model theModel) {

    // get the requested list of items to be bought
    List<Product> theProduct = productDAO.buyList();

    // add them to the page
    theModel.addAttribute("products", theProduct);

    return "buy-list";
}
```

part of my *JSP*:

```
<c:forEach var="tempProduct" items="${products}">
    <tr>
        <td>${tempProduct.productName}</td>
        <td>{tempProduct.difference}</td>
    </tr>
```

In my product entity I created a new field *difference*

```
// field for quantityNeeded-status value
@Transient
private int difference;
public int getDifference(Integer quantityNeeded,Integer status) {

    difference=quantityNeeded-status;

    return difference;
}
```

As mentioned above, the list I am showing should also have a new parameter, which will be calculated(as a difference of 2 ints from the database).This value will be shown on the page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems a good and straightforward approach, you should never propagate the domain model object outside the business layer, for instance by using entities in the front end. 
What you should do, is to create a service layer, with its own dto, where you would put all the information you need to pass to the front end.

So, if your frontend layer needs specific information from the backend, you will create a ProductDTO file with **only** the fields you need, for instance the productName and the priceDifference.

The service layer will retrieve the information from the DAO, and then translate it into the DTO, to decouple the responsibilities between the datasource and the presentation.
This way, if you change the logic of the calculation of the priceDifference, you just replace the business logic, while the presentation layer will continue working.

I would change:

```
List<Product> theProduct = productDAO.buyList();
```

to

```
List<ProductDTO> theProduct = productService.buyList();
```

The ProductDTO is a simple POJO with the fields you need and the service would have something like:

```
public List<ProductDTO> buyList() {
    List<Product> myProducts = productDAO.buyList();
    //convert the myProduct list to a list of ProductDTO
    //calculate the priceDifference
    //return the list od DTOs
    return dtoList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick dirty way -- create the correct getter

```
public int getDifference() {
   return quantityNeeded-status;
}
```

Proper way is @senape's mentioned above.